# UNIX Timestamp to MySQL DATETIME

Tags: mysql, datetime, timestamp

I have a table with statistics and a field named `time` with Unix Timestamps.

There are about 200 rows in the table, but I would like to change the Unix timestamps to MySQL DATETIME without losing the current rows. The current table:

```
CREATE TABLE `stats` (
    `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `time` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `domain` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    `user_agent` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `domain_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

So the `time` (INT) should be a DATETIME field.

How can I update the Unix Timestamp to MySQL's DATETIME?

Comment: You can see how to convert timestamp in datetime in [http://www.jordigirones.com/455-convertir-unix-timestamp-en-fecha-de-mysql.html](http://www.jordigirones.com/455-convertir-unix-timestamp-en-fecha-de-mysql.html)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Remember to test it before using it for real, this is written from memory but should give you a good idea.

```
ALTER TABLE `stats` CHANGE `time` `unix_time` int(11) NOT NULL // rename the old column
ALTER TABLE `stats` ADD `time` DATETIME NOT NULL // create the datetime column
UPDATE `stats` SET `time`=FROM_UNIXTIME(unix_time) // convert the data
ALTER TABLE `stats` DROP `unix_time` // drop the old unix time column
```

Comment: Works great, last one should be ALTER TABLE `stats`. Thanks!

Comment: Great Job! Worked Perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

1. use alter table to create a new column (eg. time2) with the datetime type in the same table
2. update stats set time2=from_unixtime(time);
3. use alter table to a) delete the time column, and b) rename the time2 to time.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE `stats`
MODIFY COLUMN `time` timestamp NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AFTER `id`;
ALTER TABLE `stats`
MODIFY COLUMN `time` datetime NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AFTER `id`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PDO example of how to use **FROM_UNIXTIME** in a prepared statement:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO " .$this->table_name.  " SET origTS=FROM_UNIXTIME(:d2)";                
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(":d2", $this->origTS);         // UNIX time [ but seconds! ]
```